# ViewPager and recyclerview cluttering

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I have this weird problem with the ViewPager, I've followed this page https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide, but I use a RecyclerView for my second fragment page instead. The first page, which is a simple framelayout fragment, is correctly rendered. But the recyclerview page  is totally cluttered (swiping to the left). Its like the first page is below and the second is copied several time on top, see  [screendump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgDUs.png). Anyone who recognizes this issue ?

```html
The ViewPager (callerpager)

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/caller_pager" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="#33b5e5"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

The RecyclerView (caller_log_list)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView android:id="@+id/caller_log_list_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />
    
The RecyclerViewItem (caller_log_list_item)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/logcreated"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:text="Oppretta"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/log"
        android:layout_width="211dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Logg"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/logcreated"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/logbillable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Fakturerbar"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/log"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/loggedby"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:text="Logget av"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logcreated" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


CallLoggerListFragment 

public class CallerLogListFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.caller_log_list, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()  {
        super.onPause();
    }

    private void refreshFragment() {
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.caller_log_list_view);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        try {
            JSONArray log = PMCallogHandler.getCurrentLogList();
            if (log.length()>0) {
                adapter = new MyAdapter(log);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser && getView()!=null) {
            System.out.println("User in the Fragment2");
            refreshFragment();
        }
        else {
            // User is not viewing the fragment,
            // or fragment is our of the screen
            System.out.println("User left Fragment2");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        refreshFragment();
    }
}

class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private JSONArray dataset;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView createdDate;
        private TextView loggedBy;
        private TextView log;
        private CheckBox isBillable;

        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            createdDate = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.logcreated);
            loggedBy = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.loggedby);
            log = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.log);
            isBillable=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.logbillable);
        }

        public void setCreatedDate(String date) {
            createdDate.setText(date);
        }
        public void setLoggedBy(String loggedBy) {
            this.loggedBy.setText(loggedBy);
        }
        public void setLog(String log) {
            this.log.setText(log);
        }
        public void setBillable(boolean isBillable) {
            this.isBillable.setChecked(isBillable);
        }
    }

    public MyAdapter(JSONArray myDataset) {
        dataset = myDataset;
    }

    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                     int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.caller_log_list_item, parent, false);

        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        JSONObject rw = null;
        try {
            rw = dataset.getJSONObject(position);
            holder.setBillable(rw.getBoolean("billable"));
            holder.setCreatedDate(rw.getString("created"));
            holder.setLog(rw.getString("title"));
            holder.setLoggedBy("...");
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataset.length();
    }
}

The LoggingActivity

public class LoggingActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private ViewPager pager = null;
    private PagerAdapter pagerAdapter=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.caller_pager);
            pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.caller_pager);
            pagerAdapter = new CallerLogPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getIntent().getExtras().getString("logResponse"));
            pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
            //pager.addOnPageChangeListener();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (pager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            pager.setCurrentItem(pager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause()  {
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class CallerLogPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        private String logResponse;
        public CallerLogPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String logResponse) {
            super(fm);
            this.logResponse=logResponse;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            if(position == 0){
              
                return "New Contact log";
            }
            else {
                return "Contact logs";
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment ret = null;
            if(position==0) {
                ret = new CallerLogFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("logResponse", logResponse.toString());
                ret.setArguments(args);
            } else if(position==1) {
                ret = new CallerLogListFragment();
                Bundle args = new Bundle();
                args.putString("contactLog", "");
                ret.setArguments(args);
            }

            return ret;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us the relevant code please - without we won't be able to help you out.

Comment: Added some code. I've not attached the CallerLogFragment, since this is working...